# How to connect 5V relay to Arduino Infiduino R3

Tags: arduino, relay, 5v

I have a 5 volt relay which I'd like to connect my bulb to and control with my Arduino. All the online tutorials have different markings on their devices from mine. I have 5V, GND, SIG on my relay and most tutorials are showing NC ,NO and CO and I am not sure which one refers to what. Can anyone advise on how to go about the connections from the Relay to the Arduino?

Comment: What is the part number of you relay?

Comment: So just 3 pins on your relay? No output pin?

Comment: @mic TIANBO HJR-3FF-S-Z

Comment: @Bradman175 3pins plus two ports to screw in the power cable

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-connect-a-single-pole-double-throw-relay-in-a-circuit

Comment: At least try to search for a diagram on the internet before asking on here. https://www.schukat.com/schukat/schukat_cms_en.nsf/index/warengruppe?OpenDocument&wg=E6437&refDoc=CMS6F4C553CBFEC9E92C125708A004D7B02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look, you have the three pins, power, ground, and signal.  Connect the 5V and Ground to the Arduino. The signal connects to the pin on the Arduino you are using to control the relay.  The other side of the board should have three screw terminals typically the middle is (C) common, the others are NO (Normally Open) and NC (Normally Closed). The contacts control your load the pins control the relay.  Using a ohm meter you will get continuity between the C and NC contacts. This is consistent with all of the Arduino relay boards I have used but I cannot say it applies to all.

Comment: makes much more sense to me than the other answers / diagrams